# htaccess rewrite non-www subfolder to www subfolder redirects to www root

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I would like to redirect

```
mydomain.com/subfolder
```

to

```
www.mydomain.com/subfolder
```

using .htaccess

This is what I have tried.

Root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Subfolder .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(subfolder(?:/.*)?)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

for a strange reason is redirecting

```
mydomain.com/subfolder
```

to

```
www.mydomain.com
```

I have tried implementing just the root .htaccess, just the subfolder .htacess, both root and subfolder .htacess, and having no .htaccess redirect, and redirecting solely using PHP redirect. All of these options route mydomain.com/subfolder to www.mydomain.com .

Is there something else that is redirecting traffic away?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you have some syntax errors in the rules. Try this in the root htaccess to redirect to `www` including subfolders.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```